# Calling the woocommerce_thankyou page function on custom template page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have made a redirect from the custom Woocommerce thankyou-page template (since it is used in the mails, and I want to customize the page completely).

Some plugins is adding actions to the "woocommerce_thankyou" filter, and I want to call these actions on my custom template.

Is that possible to add somehow?
I have tried googling, but I can't seem to find anything.

So my question is: How do I add / call the "woocommerce_thankyou" filter / action on a custom page template?